# Google Analytics GA4 - How to see Line Graph of Views for a single URL (Page path)?

Tags: google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

In Universal Analytics (UA) - it was possible to click: Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages

Then, you could select any page on your site, to see a line graph of that page.

(Example - I could click on my "Contact Us" page, and see back from January, the visitors each day, to see if certain months or days get more traffic.

Example Image of What Was Possible in UA

[image: 1]

I have tried everything - and watched YouTube videos and guides - but I cannot find anyone who seems to have used this feature, or a solution to recreate this in GA4.

Did nobody want to see how single pages performed?

Thanks for any help.

I would like to be able to see the Views for a single page using Google Analytics GA4.

So I can look at "Contact Us" page, and see the number of views each day for a set amount of time

Comment: Did you try the explorer? In GA4, if default report is not what you are looking for, you can build an explorer report very easily